# When is a wish not a proposition?

Tags: logic, linguistics, propositions

Consider these sentences:

```
S1. Would that Los Angeles were not that far away.
S2. I really wish Los Angeles were nearer to New York.
S3. I wish that Los Angeles were not that far away.
S4. It is going to rain tomorrow.
```

According to Smith (2012), **S1** represents a non-propositional wish and **S2** represents a proposition. It is clear **S2** is resolved as a proposition because it represents a state of the world. Why is **S1** not a proposition if **S3** is clearly a proposition in the same way as **S2**? Does this mean **S1** does not reference a state of the world? I understand some might argue **S1** is referencing a state in the future and as opposed to a current state. But we do not apply the same reasoning to **S4**. What makes **S1** different from **S3**?

#### References

1. Smith, N. J. (2012). Propositions and Arguments. In Logic: The laws of truth (p. 6). Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press.

Comment: Not clear... I think that S2 and S3 are "similar"; according to Smith they are not ? They both express a *fact* about me and my wishes.

Comment: Maybe S1 is not because it does not refer the wish to some person wishing, and thus we cannot judge its truth value.

Comment: The discussion about *propositions* is sometimes slippery... See page 5 for examples: "The snow is white". You can add theorems of mathematics and geometry as examples.

Comment: Examples of non-propositions: questions, commands, exclamations

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Yes that's why it was confusing to me. I agree, to Smith S2 and S3 are similar. S1 does seem to refer to the person wishing it though. When I think of S1, I appear to be thinking S3 in my mind. "The snow is white" is propositional by virtue of the structure of the sentence indicating that P(x). But sentences are shortcuts and not 1:1 maps to logic. So intuition plays a lot as well. For instance, when in a conversation, it is not unusual to respond with "Yeah" or "Correct" to S1. Why would someone do that if it were non-propositional?

Comment: Beliefs are propositional attitudes. With propositional attitudes we determine whether or not the belief is held and utterly disregard whether or not the belief is true. It looks like your "wishes" are the same kind of thing. They are true or false based on the actual mental state, not the object of the wish. S2 and S3 are like propositional attitudes in that their truth value depends on the actual mental state and not the object of the wish.

Comment: The issue is exactly that logic is not "conversation": there is no context, time, etc. but only statement expressing a "content" that must "fit" with reality (in which case the statement is true: **2+2=4**) or does not (in which case it is false: **2+2=5**).

Comment: I agree logic is not about conversation or even propositional content for that matter. I am wondering if there is a predominant reason why Smith labels S1 as non-propositional apart from it simply being an exclamation. Has the body of research ruled out all exclamations being propositional? It is not obvious to me all exclamations are non-propositional.

@polcott Are there ways in which people think S1 is not a proposition in reference to mental states? What else could it refer to?

Comment: My parsing of ye olde English is not good enough to be sure what S1 is saying. To me it seems to be saying the same ting as S2 and S3. "Would it be so" seems to be the ye olde English for "I wish". Some exclamations can be propositions: "Wow you bought me a new car" Others cannot: "Damn!".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Smith defines a proposition as an expression that is either true or false. **S2**, **S3**, and **S4** are plausibly interpreted as descriptions of the world, and so true or false. For example, it may be true or false that, say, the speaker wishes Los Angeles were not that far away, as in **S3**. In this case, **S3** is a description of the speaker's mental state.

**S1**, in contrast, seems interpreted by Smith as the speaker wishing, rather than describing the speaker wishing. Contrast this with a descriptions of the activity (for speaker "T"; spoken by someone who witnessed T express S1):

**S5** T wishes that Los Angeles were not that far away

**S6** T said **S1**

Both **S5** and **S6** are propositional, since they're true or false.

On a related note: I'm surprised to see mention of wishing here. I used wishing as an example of an attitude one might use to introduce impossible content that couldn't be captured in semantic theories restricted to (even very sophisticated accounts of) propositions in [this paper](https://philpapers.org/rec/BEVCWY); in my research I never came across this text, so thank you.

If you're interested, I'd argued expressions like:

**S7**. I wish I could imagine a round square.

Had plausible readings in which speakers knowingly wish for impossible content. For example, after years of trying and failing to imagine a round square (an impossible task) out of frustration I express S4. I know the content is impossible; I wish it anyway.

Comment: That doesn't sound right since Smith argues on the previous page that impossibilities can be propositional with "Snow is green". I personally don't think the average person would ever argue that wishes can be non-propositional. For instance they wouldn't do that for "want", why would they for "wish"?

Comment: Although S4 itself is non-propositional because the properties are mutually exclusive. Whereas S1 doesn't hinge on the properties being exclusive in the same sentence (far away and not far away at the same time).

Comment: First thing, Smith does not claim "Snow is green" is an impossible proposition. He claims it's a false proposition. Second, "want" is distinguished from "wish" in that the latter but not the former can be for impossible content, and this seems to have empirical backing among average English speakers. Third, "impossible" is ambiguous. I was suggesting S1 (epistemically) impossible content; S4 involves (metaphysically) impossible content. Fourth, having looked at the Smith, S3 describes a mental state of wishing; S1 expresses a wish, only the description is true or false here.

Comment: You're right Smith doesn't claim directly it's an impossibility (my bad). I believed it reasonable to infer that Smith means snow cannot be green because of metaphysical impossibility and as a result was a false proposition. Anyways your last few sentences clarified how Smith really may have meant it (although I don't agree with him on this yet). "Wishing" as being qualitatively different from descriptions of it. If this is what you mean, please add it to the answer and I'll mark as accepted answer. Thanks!

Comment: Updated my answer; I'm with you, I'm not sure I agree with Smith on this point either, but that does seem to be what he means. Thanks again for pointing this text out!